# Update Datagridview on Data change

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, sql-server-ce

I know that there are some threads about my problem, but I haven't found the right answer yet.
My Problem:
I have a SQL-CE-database where one table gets data from another thread.
In my application I want a Datagridview to "watch" this table and refresh it when data changes.

I allready tried many things e.g.

```cs
BindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

or

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = TableAdapterName;
```

Thank you for your help!

Max.

Edit: It would be helpful, if someone can tell me how to trigger the update of the Datagridview with a button. Thanks!

Comment: are you try to perform `dataGridView1.Refresh()` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `dataGridView1.Refresh();` bound to a Button-onClick event. Didn't work.

Comment: I just found the solution for my problem:
The `TableAdapter` needs the `ConnectionString` before you can "re`fill`" it.

Didn't know that...